Unsure where SonarQube results are being published
I am running SonarQube where I am configuring the cxx plugin by running sonar.cppcheck.reportpaths=./test.xml
this is what my sonar.properties file looks like:
# Project identification
sonar.projectKey=sonar
sonar.projectName=sonarqube_project
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
 
# Leave sonar.sources empty
sonar.sources=test
#sonar.language=cpp
sonar.language=cxx
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.cxx.file.suffixes=.c,.h
sonar.cppcheck.reportPaths=./test.xml
#sonar.cxx.compiler.parser=MSBuild
#sonar.cxx.compiler.reportPath=*.log
#sonar.cxx.compiler.charset=UTF-8S

I would like to have the Cppcheck results be published on the SonarQube website.
Currently, what I see on the website is that it is scanning over the Python and HTML files, but not c files. I am wondering what I am doing wrong.
Here is the remote pipeline that calls the SAST scan.
#version: v4.3.2
variables:
    SAST_IMAGE: "cdn.harbor.global.lmco.com/lmc.eo.asap/lmco-security/static-code-scanner:latest"
    ENABLE_SAST_SCANS: "true"
    SAST_ALLOW_FAIL: "false"
    # See documentation for additional variables https://pipeline-cSatalog.global.lmco.com/#/pipelines/sast-scans/docs/sast-basic.md

    # variable for tracking pipeline usage
    SWF_PIPELINE_METRICS_MODULES_SAST_SONARQUBE: "true"
.sonarqube-scan:
    image: $SAST_IMAGE
    stage: sast
    variables:
        SAST_SCAN: "sonarqube"
        NEXUS_URL: "https://nexus.global.lmco.com"
    before_script:
        - echo -e " -- Docs -- \n pipeline_module \n - modules/sast-sonarqube.gitlab-ci.yml \n expected files \n - none \n variables \n - ADDITIONAL_PATH \t\t\t  ${ADDITIONAL_PATH} \n - ENFORCE_RELEASE_GATE \t\t  ${ENFORCE_RELEASE_GATE} \n - SCAN_RESULTS_REVIEWERS_NTIDS  ${SCAN_RESULTS_REVIEWERS_NTIDS} \n - ENABLE_RESULTS_EMAIL \t\t  ${ENABLE_RESULTS_EMAIL} \n"
        - "if [ -z ${CI_PROJECT_NAME+x} ]; then\n  echo \"**********************************************************************************************************\"\n  echo -e \"\\e[91mYou appear to be missing variables normally provided by GitLab. If you are executing \\e[0m\" \n  echo -e \"\\e[91myour pipeline from Jenkins, variable mapping documentation can be found here: \\e[0m\"\n  echo -e \"\\e[34mhttps://docs.us.lmco.com/display/CASAP/ASAP-General-008+-+How+to+Configure+Security+Scanning+for+Bitbucket \\e[0m\"\n  echo \"**********************************************************************************************************\"\n  exit 1\nfi\n"
        - >
          if [ -n "${ADDITIONAL_PATH}" ] && [ "$ADDITIONAL_PATH" != "." ]; then

            FILE="${ADDITIONAL_PATH}/sonar-project.properties"
            if [ -f "$FILE" ];
            then
              echo "Copying sonar-project.properties to repo root."
              cp "$FILE" "./sonar-project.properties"
            fi
          fi

    script:
        - python /static-code-scan.py
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - sonarqubescan-metrics.json
        when: always
sonarqube-scan:
    extends: .sonarqube-scan
    rules:
        - if: '$ENABLE_SAST_SCANS == "false"'
          when: never
        - if: '$SAST_ALLOW_FAIL=="true"'
          allow_failure: true
        - if: '$SAST_ALLOW_FAIL=="false"'
          allow_failure: false


Are you using the paid or the free version of sonarqube? If you are using the free version, Do you have the C++ Community plugin installed?

Yes, i believe i have the plugin installed.

Check sonarserver/api/plugins/installed There should be a plugin mentioning C++
